# Where should I put class files that are used only from rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class `Foo` that is used only from rake task, and the class need to require `nokogiri`.

Currently I'm writing in `Gemfile` like this:

```
gem 'nokogiri', require: false
```

And put the class file in `config/initializer/foo.rb`.

```
require 'nokogiri'
class Foo
...
end
```

I know if I require a gem in initializer directory, `require: false` in Gemfile is meaningless.

Where should I put file in the case like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First, you can always put your class file to `app/models`, if it represents some data or data processing - `app/modles` is not only for ActiveRecord, you know. Any pure-ruby class can be a model too. ;)
- you can safely require `nokigiri` from that file and use that class from `rake` task - everything should be all right. There is no need to require `nokigiri` from initializers/gemfile, unless you're using it somewhere else too.
- why would you like to not require `nokigiri` from Gemfile, by the way?

Comment: As you say, I thought `app/models` are only for `ActiveRecord`, thanks! I don't require `nokogiri` from Gemfile because it's better for performance a little bit, isn't it?

Comment: @Tetsu, you may be doing premature optimization by that, and, in my experience, it can consume alot of your time without any real benefit. When you'll get to the point, where performance really matters, I suggest you to profile your app and improve performance of the most "heavy" parts (or the parts, that are called most frequently). So, profile; find the piece which impacts the performance most; fix; repeat until you get performance you want.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll follow it.